# php decode base64 from UTF-16

Tags: php, base64, decode, utf-16

I have string that create by mssql that base64 of utf-16 string:

```
SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBPAHIAbABkAA==
```

The decoded version is :

```
Hello WOrld
```

This is .NET tools that can use be for decode http://www5.rptea.com/base64/ (Use UTF-16)

How can i convert this using php mb or base64 ?

This is my convertion that return wrong characters:

```
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding(base64_decode('SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBPAHIAbABkAA=='), "UTF-8", "UTF-16"));

// string(33) "䠀攀氀氀漀 圀伀爀氀搀"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"UTF-16" is big endian, but your text is encoded little endian. Use "UTF-16LE" instead.